# Failed to create new MeanIO package. Require dependency 'access'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I had encouraged a weird problem when setting up a MeanIO project.

Step 1: I to create a skeleton project, using:

```
mean init myApp
```

Step 2: I removed all defaults package from the created project, using:

```
mean package -d access
mean package -d articles
mean package -d system
mean package -d users
```

Step 3: I created a package, using:

```
mean package backend
```

Step 4: I started my project, using:

```
npm install && grunt
```

Then I got an error output:

```
Error: dependency 'access' was not registered.
```

If I skipped **step 3**, everything was okay.

I have no idea what is wrong in my steps. Does anyone tell me a clue?

Answer (score 2):

I think you only can remove "articles".
The other packages tied deeply with meanio.

Comment: That is correct. access and system packages are used as part of the 'core'. You are able to create you own custom access and system packages if so desired